# How to parse a web service returned response into an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, web-services, drupal-6

I am updating my question with a few breakthroughs i was able to achieve today. I used get_object_vars.
This code was able to print out the value i am trying to iterate over.

```
         $fileStatus = $ServicesLink->GetFileStatus(array('Ticket'=>$ticket,'ProjectID'=>$pidobtained,'SourceLanguageID'=> "", 'TargetLanguageID'=> "",'FileID'=> "",'Filename'=>""));
            $arrayPid = array();

            foreach($fileStatus->GetFileStatusResult->FileStatuses->FileStatus as $fileStatusObtained)
            {
                $arrayPid = get_object_vars($fileStatusObtained);
                //$arrayPid =$fileStatusObtained ;
            }

            echo is_array($arrayPid) ? 'Array' : 'not an Array';
            echo "<br>";

            echo("Count of array ".count($arrayPid));
            echo "<br>";
            print_r('<pre>'. print_r($arrayPid) .'</pre>');
```

This http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-1163-165.html is what i saw as a result.

Now since this Object has objects inside it along with the values i need i.e. FileID,FileName etc. I am seeing the error message but a glimpse of the output. The code i used was this (just a very minor change from the above. I used a foreach)

```
  $fileStatus = $ServicesLink->GetFileStatus(array('Ticket'=>$ticket,'ProjectID'=>$pidobtained,'SourceLanguageID'=> "", 'TargetLanguageID'=> "",'FileID'=> "",'Filename'=>""));
            $arrayPid = array();

            foreach($fileStatus->GetFileStatusResult->FileStatuses->FileStatus as $fileStatusObtained)
            {
                $arrayPid = get_object_vars($fileStatusObtained);
                //$arrayPid =$fileStatusObtained ;
            }

            echo is_array($arrayPid) ? 'Array' : 'not an Array';
            echo "<br>";

            echo("Count of array ".count($arrayPid));
            echo "<br>";
            //print_r('<pre>'. print_r($arrayPid) .'</pre>');


            foreach($arrayPid as $val) {
                echo ($val);
                echo "<br>";
            } 


        }
```

As a result of this i saw the following output http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-1163-166.html .
The index number 1 occupies the object and hence the error for string conversion.
If i use a For loop instead of the foreach in the code just above,i am unable to print the values.
I tried:

```
            for($i=0;$i<(count($arrayPid));$i+=1)
            {
              echo($arrayPid[$i]);
            }
```

But this would print nothing.

Could any one help me with a way so that i can iterate and have the values inside that array $arrayPid.

Would like to have your suggestions, views, doubts on the same.
I am sorry that i am using imageshare but that is the only way i can share my screens.

Thanks 
Angie

Comment: Which library are you using to do the soap request?

Comment: I am not using any Soap library as such. I just call using the url. This code works. The one for GetSourceLanguages provides the result. My query is directed more towards how to extract out the values for the array $fileStatus .The statement **GetSourceLanguagesResult->Languages->Language as $language** works while **GetFileStatusResult->FileStatuses->FileStatus as $fileStatusObtained** does not. I am trying to confirm whether the xml tags in the web services are being parsed properly. @emaillenin I hope my query is a bit more clearer now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use it is:

```
       foreach($fileStatus->GetFileStatusResult->FileStatuses->FileStatus as $fileStatusObtained)
            {
                $arrayPid = get_object_vars($fileStatusObtained);
                //print_r($fileStatusObtained->FileID);                 
                 $fileId [] = $fileStatusObtained->FileID;
                                               ...
                                              }
```